# fpdf traer informacion segun el usuario logueado php mysql

Tags: mysql, pdf, fpdf, reporte

Ocupo traer informacion del usuario que esta en la session activa usando mi id primaria y que cuando se carge otro usuario le de informacion respectiva a su id que le pertenece, realemente le intente pero no encuentro la manera de resolverlo.

Este es mi codigo.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['idempleado'])) {
    $resultado['estado'] = "¡No tiene permisos para acceder!";
    echo json_encode($resultado);
    die();
}
    include 'plantillarecibo.php';
    require 'conexionreportes.php';
  $idempleado;
  $query = "SELECT Nombre, Cantidad, PrecioUnit,  Importe, DescripcionProducto FROM vsttblreservacionempleado WHERE ID = $idempleado AND  EstatusReservacion = 'Activo'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);

    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $pdf->Cell(50,6,'Nombre',1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,'Cantidad',1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,'PrecioUnit',1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,'Importe',1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,'Producto',1,1,'C',1);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {

        $pdf->Cell(50,6,utf8_decode($row['Nombre']),1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,$row['Cantidad'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,$row['PrecioUnit'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,$row['Importe'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,$row['DescripcionProducto'],1,1,'C');
    }
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: A simple vista el error se debe a que no estas "_seteando_" la variable `$idempleado`, es decir, se me ocurre que debería ser `$idempleado = $_SESSION['idempleado'];` (_línea 10 aprox._)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda; lo incorporé y funcionó perfectamente. realmente se me paso de vista eso.